# Polymer ¿Como generar marker de google-map desde un fichero xml dinámicamente?

Tags: polymer

Soy nuevo en Polymer y estoy haciendo una pequeña página que sitúe mediante geolocalización mi posición. Adicionalmente, tengo un fichero xml con una serie de sitios elegidos al azar con diferente información, entre las que están la latitud, longitud y el nombre (que será lo que quiero pasar como "title" al marker). Mi problema está en que me está costando mucho sacar los diferentes puntos de forma dinámica, ya que empleo un dom-repeat, pero solo puedo realizar un filtro por función y no soy capaz de conseguir que en el googl-map-marker se cargen correctamente los resultados del fichero xml.
Os pongo el código que he desarrollado a modo de prueba:

Fichero XML:

```
<Contenidos>
<contenido>   
    <atributos idioma="es">
        <atributo nombre="NOMBRE">Plaza Mayor</atributo>
        <atributo nombre="LATITUD">40.41583855082183</atributo>
        <atributo nombre="LONGITUD">-3.7074257084323636</atributo>
   </atributo>
  </atributos>      
<contenido>  
    <atributos idioma="es">     
        <atributo nombre="NOMBRE">Aeropuerto Barajas</atributo>      
            <atributo nombre="LATITUD">40.45188738242834</atributo>
            <atributo nombre="LONGITUD">-3.5859807207200376</atributo>
        </atributo>          
    </atributos>
</contenido>
<contenido>    
    <atributos idioma="es">  
        <atributo nombre="NOMBRE">Aeropuerto Barajas Terminal 4</atributo>
            <atributo nombre="LATITUD">40.45188738242834</atributo>
            <atributo nombre="LONGITUD">-3.5859807207200376</atributo>
        </atributo>
    </atributos>
</contenido>
```

Código en Polymer:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/google-map/google-map.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/google-map/google-map-marker.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/geo-location/geo-location.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-repeat.html">


<dom-module id="museo-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <style>
      google-map {
        height: 600px;
      }
    </style>
     <iron-ajax auto
      url="http://127.0.0.1:8081/info2.xml" 
      handle-as="xml" 
      on-response="_on_response"
      last-response="{{response}}"
      >
     </iron-ajax>

    <h2>Ejemplo Página [[prop1]]!</h2>
    <geo-location latitude="{{latitude}}" longitude="{{longitude}}" fit-to-marker></geo-location>
    <p>Latitud: [[latitude]]</p>
    <p>Longitud: [[longitude]]</p>


    <p>Resultado de Latitud:</p>
    <google-map latitude=[[latitude]] longitude=[[longitude]] >
        <google-map-marker latitude=[[latitude]] longitude=[[longitude]] title="Mi casa" ></google-map-marker> 

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{nodeList(atributo,'atributo')}}" filter="Info" as="marker" >

                <google-map-marker latitude="[[Latitud(marker)]]" longitude="[[Longitud(marker)]]"  title="Pruebas"></google-map-marker> 


        </template>
  </google-map>


  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     */
    class MuseoApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'museo-app'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            value: 'museo-app'
          }
        }


        }

      }
      Polymer({

        is: "museo-app",

        nodeList: function(element,name){

            return element ?
            Array.prototype.slice.call(element.querySelectorAll(name)) : []
        },

          Info: function(item){

             var lat, long, titulo;
             if(item.getAttribute('nombre')=='LATITUD'){

                 console.log("Nombre atributo: " +item.getAttribute('nombre'));
                 console.log("valor atributo : " +item.innerHTML);

                 lat=item.innerHTML;
                 //return lat;

                }


                if(item.getAttribute('nombre')=='LONGITUD'){

                 console.log("Nombre atributo: " +item.getAttribute('nombre'));
                 console.log("valor atributo : " +item.innerHTML);
                 long=item.innerHTML;
                 return long;
             }

              if(item.getAttribute('nombre')=='NOMBRE'){


                 console.log("Nombre atributo: " +item.getAttribute('nombre'));
                 console.log("valor atributo : " +item.innerHTML);
                 titulo=item.innerHTML;
                 console.log("titulo: "  +item.innerHTML);
                 return titulo;
             }


          },

        _on_response : function(r){

        response = r.detail.response;
        this.nombre=response;
        this.atributo=response;
        this.atributos=response;
        this.contenido=response;

        },

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

En los shadow-dom de los google-map-marker veo que los item de latitud y longitud los sitúa en el title. ¿Cómo puedo controlar la disposición de los datos del xml dentro del google-map-marker de forma ordenada?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda:

Alejandro